# Open source game like "Last War: Survival Game"

Tags: game

I've recently noticed an Android game that is massively advertised called "Last War: Survival Game". Unfortunately, the ratings are saying this is just a Pay2Win game. Meaning to have fun with it you need to invest with cash. Even more: the comments say that the advertisments are showing only 10% of the gameplay, while the other 90% are quite boring village/city building.

I'm only interested in the 10% gameplay. Is there a preferrably open source game that has a likewise gameplay, where you are a soldier (or something like that) which is running in one direction and is shooting down the enemy soldiers? That soldier can increase its power by shooting down power-ups. Note that the power-ups need a certain amount of hits before they are activated.

It doesn't need to be on Android. I'm generally open for any platform.

[image: Screen of the game]

I'd like to show another game whose game play would suite me:

[image: Another game]

Here you're dragging your army over bridges where the calculation would change the amount of soldiers. And then you need to stand against the enemy army. Not sure about the name.